# Apache ProxyPass Based on Request URI Length

Tags: regex, apache

I've got a problem with Apache ProxyPass (more specifically ProxyPassMatch) where I'm trying to proxy https://domain.com/{6 character key} to another server.

I've tried regex's like the following (attempting to take into consideration multiple ways that this might be handled by Apache):

```
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{22,22}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{7,7}$/g"   https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{14,14}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{23,23}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{21,21}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{8,8}$/g"   https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{6,6}$/g"   https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{15,15}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
ProxyPassMatch "/^.{13,13}$/g" https://domain.com/api/{6 character key}
```

However nothing seems to work. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## The fix

You need to capture the characters in the pattern and then reference them in the url:

Example from the docs:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.gif)$" "http://backend.example.com/$1"
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch

So in your case I think what you want is:

```
ProxyPassMatch "/^(.{6})$/"   "https://domain.com/api/$1"
```

## Why/How this works

When using regular expressions, you can capture matched text by using brackets and then reference them using $1 for the first set of brackets, $2 for the second etc.

e.g.

```
   ProxyPassMatch "/^(.{6})/(.{6})$/"   "https://domain.com/api/$2/$1"
```

Would match `http://domain.com/123456/ABCDEF` and proxy to `https://domain.com/api/ABCDEF/123456`

## One more thing

Also note you don't need `{6,6}` and can just use `{6}` to say you need the character to match exactly 6 times, you use this format where you want a variable number of characters e.g. `{4,6}` for between 4 and 6 - you can also specify `{4,}` for 4 or more.